# Invariant Violation: ListView has been removed from React Native. See fb.me/nolistview for more information or use `deprecated`

Tags: react-native, listview, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I already remove all my ListView component, and also I have no Icon or Spinner component that's I import from react-native or native-base. But it's still getting back this error, can anybody help me plz. I stuck here. But I need a solution very badly.

[image]

Comment: try to restart npm server after clearing npm cache

Comment: Not working. Can you suggest me any other way?

Comment: did you tried removing node modules and installing again ?

Comment: I do that many times.

Comment: maybe some third party library that you are using , has listview behind the scene.